# Replacing Light Switch / Extra Wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am trying to replace a light switch and am a little confused at the addition of what appears to be an extra wire:

Current switch wiring:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c58qw5wbno20qhr/IMG_4160.JPG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmfouqxblht1eiz/IMG_4159.JPG?dl=0

New switch I want to replace it with:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9114mvee5v13pyb/IMG_4161.JPG?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/elsxlqvw61vhvv0/IMG_4162.JPG?dl=0

This switch does control a light that is also controlled at 2 other light switches in the house, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

The switch next to this one was previously a dimmer but I have already removed that!

How do I hook this up if I only have 2 brass screws on the new one?

Comment: To answer your next question,  the black screw (labeled common  )  is super important. The brass screws are the two travelers and they are interchangeable.    The wire colors are not important.    The screw positions are not important *and will not be consistent from switch to switch*.

Answer (score 5):

The existing switch is a three way switch, and the new one is not.  You’ll need to get a three-way switch to replace it.